# How to get the best match when searching through documents using marqo

Tags: python

whenever i use the `search()` method to search through documents on marqo i get a list of python dictionaries as the result, arranging them from best to least matching but i only want the best matching to show not a list of dictionaries. is there any method to accomplish that? Here is what the result look like:

```
{
    'hits': [
        {   
            'Title': first_documents title,
            'Description': first_documents description,
            '_highlights': {
                'Description': the part of the document that matches the best,
            },
            '_id': document_id,
            '_score': 1.2387788
        }, 
        {   
            'Title': second_documents title,
            'Description':second_documents description,
            '_highlights': {'Title': the part that matches the best},
            '_id': document_id,
            '_score': 1.2047464
        }
    ],
    'limit': 10,
    'processingTimeMs': 49,
    'query': search_query }
```

and this is what i am aiming for:

```
{
        'hits': [
            {   
                'Title': first_documents title,
                'Description': first_documents description,
                '_highlights': {
                    'Description': the part of the document that matches the best,
                },
                '_id': document_id,
                '_score': 1.2387788
            }],
        'limit': 10,
        'processingTimeMs': 49,
        'query': search_query }
```

i have tried using list index to get the first one and it worked but i want to know if there is any method i can use directly from [marqo](https://marqo.pages.dev/)

Comment: Edit your question to show exactly what library you are talking about (what is "marqo", at least add a link to its documentation), and what is the current code that you have, where exactly are you stuck right now... -- [mre] -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the `search()` method you can pass a keyword argument which is `limit` by default it is set to 10 but by changing it to 1 you will get only the first one.
here is what i mean;

```
  mq.index(your_index).search(
        q=search_query, 
        limit=1
    )
```